# Multiplication beetween matrices with Identity Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I've got this matrix product, where B is non-singular matrix and I is the identity matrix.

$M = BIB^{-1}$

Is it lecit to write $M = BIB^{-1}=IBB^{-1}$ ? If yes, what principle (or theorem) allows me to do it ?

Comment: Notice that the $n\times n$ identity matrix is special in the sense that for any other $n\times n$ matrix $A$, one has that $A=IA=AI$.  So, yes... $BIB^{-1}=(BI)B^{-1}=(B)B^{-1}=(IB)B^{-1}=I(BB^{-1})=II=I$

Comment: Thanks , if you write it as an answer i vote you

Answer (score 0):

It's simple matrix product. The identity matrix $I$ is the *multiplicative unit*,  meaning the easily verifiable fact that
$$IB=B\ \text{ and} \ BI=B$$
for any other $n\times n$ matrix $B$. In particular, $I$ *commutes* with every matrix, and we indeed have
$$BIB^{-1}=IBB^{-1}=I\,. $$